# Yii CUploadedFile from raw base64 data

Tags: base64, yii

Is it possible to create an instance of the CUploadedFile class from raw base64 data sent through a POST variable? I know I could also save the file without using this class, but I need to reuse a model class which uses CUploadedFile to get a file that was uploaded through a form.

I cannot use any file uploader component since my Yii application is a web service. It gets all its input data from POST variables.

Answer (score 2):

`CUploadedFile` — no but you can try overriding `prefetchFiles` method in your own class that extends `CUploadedFile` to fetch data from `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES`.